# FireBase Retrieval Concept

Tags: firebase

Im new to Firebase, I have Structure my Data on firebase using Indices for maintaining relationshi as described in below articles

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html

I just want to clear my retrieval concept on firebase.

as mention in above links

```
{  
  links:{  
    link1:{  
      title:"Example",
      href:"http://example.org",
      submitted:"user1",
      comments:{  
        comment1:true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when I access link1, response contains link1 data as well as comments: {comment1:true}. Instead of comment1 actual text, accessing link1 gives comment's ID i.e, comment1. its mean when I access link1, it gives me the Ids of comments belongs to that link. so I have to retrieve comments mannually requesting firebase again based on comments ids received in link1 response? Please clear my concept : )

Comment: @Grant , Firebase preffered flatten data. You can see here .https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html

Comment: @Grant . Code is just a sample. my actual work is not on links and comments but something likes it. one to many relation

Comment: @Grant. I have took this piece of code from article which I mention above in comments

Comment: Yes, you will indeed have to load each items. Essentially you're doing a client-side join operation. Contrary to what many developers expect, this is a quite fast operation in Firebase for reasonable sizes lists. See my answer here for why that is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: Is the goal to get all the comments for link1?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks Sir. For explaining moree..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your concept is correct, you will flatten out the data in firebase and then retrieve comments by using the id from the previous read

Comment: means? I have to make two requests to firebase? one for links data and then comment? if one link have hundred comments then will have to make 100 requests to get comment text?

Comment: you may need to make 100 queries but that won't translate to 100 HTTP requests due to the fact firebase uses sockets

Comment: Thanxxx Buddy, You help me in to improve my concept